# Learning resources - stack machines, JVM especially

Tags: jvm, stack-machine

I'm curious if anyone have any really good tutorials/articles/books for learning about stack machines in general, and the JVM in particular. I know these ones:

http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/applets/EternalMath.html

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibm/library/it-haggar_bytecode/

http://www.theserverside.com/tt/articles/article.tss?l=GuideJavaBytecode

Appearently the books Inside the JVM by Bill Winners and Programming for the JVM are good, even though they are old.

These are all on my "toread" list, for rainy autumn weekends.

Anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned what the JVM did by reading The "Java Virtual Machine Specification" by Tim Lindholm back in 1999.

I don't really know where to find as good a resource about more modern technologies like the JIT compilation that the Hotspot VM can do.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a lot of what I was looking for now, in the final chapter of "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs". You are going to have to read through all the book though since they constantly build on examples and concepts from earlier on.