# How does a register machine differ from a stack machine?

Tags: cpu-architecture, stack-machine

How does a register machine differ from a stack machine?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_machine and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_machine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179478/learning-resources-stack-machines-jvm-especially<br/>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622530/what-exactly-is-a-register-machine<br/>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164143/registers-vs-stacks

Comment: Wikipedia lost me at "The register machine gets its name from its one or more "registers" -- in place of a Turing machine's tape and head (or tapes and heads) the model uses multiple, uniquely-addressed registers, each of which holds a single positive integer."